# Cannot Instantiate class TestRunner:Using Cucumber with TestNG for Selenium Code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

I am getting the following error while running my Cucumber TestRunner.java class from TestNG. I have tried running **Selenium.java** file after replacing the method as **psvm**,it works fine but if i replace back the method as **Selenium_Setup()** then it is providing issue while tryng to execute from **TestNG(Cucumber Execute.java class)**So, I am not able to find out any issue in initialising webdriver. Sharing the errors and all relevant files :-

```
Can anyone please help
```

**Error Description:-**

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.2
    org.testng.TestNGException: 
    Cannot instantiate class testRunner.Execute
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
        at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
        at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
        at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:27)
        at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_5$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_5.java:63)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:43)
        at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:29)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:96)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:63)
        at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.<init>(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:33)
        at testRunner.Execute.<init>(Execute.java:14)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:37)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.<init>(JavaBackend.java:65)
        ... 36 more


    Below is the code for **Execute.java**(Cucumber TestRunner) file

    package testRunner;

    @CucumberOptions(

    features="D:\\eclipse-workspace\\CucumberWithTestNGForSelenium\\src\\test\\java\\featureFiles\\CreateAccount.feature",glue="stepDefinition"
    )
    public class Execute extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    }


    Below is the code for **Selenium.java** file 

    package testRunner;
    public class Selenium {
        public  WebDriver driver;

        public void Selenium_Setup() throws IOException
        //public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Mehak\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
              Properties prop=new Properties();
                FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D:\\eclipse-workspace\\CucumberWithTestNGForSelenium\\src\\test\\java\\ObjectRepository\\Configuration.properties");
                prop.load(fis);
                String WebsiteURL=prop.getProperty("URL");
                driver.get(WebsiteURL);
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }   

    }

    And,below is my **CreateAccount.featur**e feature file:-
    @tag
    Feature: Create New Account
     I want to use this template for my feature file

    @Test
       Scenario Outline: Create New Account by adding Multiple Users
        Given Enter the URL and Click on SignIn button
        When The EMailId is provided and Click on Create an account
        Then Fill the Personal Information Details for the "<email>" in step
        And Click on Register
        And After Clicking on Register goahead and verify the "<status>" in step


        Examples: 
          |email|status|
          | abc@gmail.com |failure for Incorrect Mobile number|
          |akapo@yahoo.in|failure for validation errors|
```

And below is my StepDefinition file as **CreateAccount.java**

```
    public class CreateAccount extends Selenium{
        ObjectLocatorsForHomePage obj=new ObjectLocatorsForHomePage();


        @Given("^Enter the URL and Click on SignIn button$")
        @Test
        public void enter_the_URL_and_Click_on_SignIn_button() throws IOException  {
            Selenium sel=new Selenium();
            sel.Selenium_Setup();
          System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.SignInbutton)).click();
           }

 Sharing the **pom.xml** file also for dependencies version of Cucumber,testNG and Selenium:-


  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8.7</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: Any reason ur using an old testng version? Use the latest and try 6.14.3

Comment: Yea,Its also not working If I upgrade the version to 6.14.3. I guess this is not the TestNG issue also.Because I had tried creating one class and then a method inside with @Test annotation so that is not throwing TestNG error.

Comment: So, not sure,where the error is

Comment: The cucumber jars u are using is old too. Use cucumber 2 and make sure the versions of all cucumber jars are same.

Comment: Yes,Its resolved now. The Cucumber testNg jar needs to be upgraded to 1.2.5.Its working now.Thanks alot :)